# How to get PDF File Path In Android 11 and 12

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I tried much code for getting pdf path in android 11 or 12 but only working in android 10 or below devices.
Can you please help me? I share my code of lines

**Intent calling like this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            statusAdapter = "pdf";
            pos = position;
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            someActivityResultLauncher.launch(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"));
```

```
someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data == null) {
                            //error
                            return;
                        }
                        try {
                            final Uri pdfUri= data.getData();
                            File pdfFile = new File(getPath(pdfUri));
                            long length = pdfFile.length();
                            length = length / 1024;
                            Toast.makeText(CreateSubEventActivity.this, "File Path : " + pdfFile.getPath() + ", File size : " + length + " KB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            uploadFile(imageFile);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(CreateSubEventActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**getPath calling like this**

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: `File pdfFile = new File(getPath(pdfUri));` That is nonsense. Dont try to get a path.

Comment: `uploadFile(imageFile);` Change to `uploadFile(data.getData());`

Comment: I need file not URI for uploadFile method

Comment: You should change your uploadFile method to take an uri. (everybody did aslready as you would know if you readed stackoverflow pages now and then).

Comment: I tried but it's not working

Comment: If you were serious you had posted your code and exactly told what not worked. Nobody can help you if you keep it this vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access a File or want a file path from a Uri that was returned from MediaStore, I have got a [library](https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT) that handles all the exceptions you might get. This includes all files on the disk, internal and removable disk. When selecting a File from Dropbox, for example, the File will be copied to your applications directory where you have full access, the copied file path will then be returned.

Comment: The library allows you to get the PATH of pdf and other files or only videos and photos???? @Mohammed Faizan

Comment: @Osdward anything you want for all file formats.

Answer (score 1):

> This one helps in my case on Android 11 hope anyone gets this helpful

```
    private String copyFile(Uri uri, String newDirName) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;

    Cursor returnCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, new String[]{
            OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE
    }, null, null, null);

    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));

    File output;
    if (!newDirName.equals("")) {
        File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        output = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name);
    } else {
        output = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "/" + name);
    }
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        int read = 0;
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }

    return output.getPath();
}
```

> String newPath =  copyFileToInternalStorage(uri, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my experience to fix this stuff after so reading all.

Get input stream from URI

```
final Uri pdfUri= data.getData();
getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdfUri)
```

then do your stuff with InputStream, like I have uploaded pdf using okHttp

```
try {

RequestBody pdffile = new RequestBody() {
    @Override public MediaType contentType() { return MediaType.parse("application/pdf"); }
    @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        Source source = null;
        try {
            source = Okio.source(inputStream);
            sink.writeAll(source);
        } finally {
            Util.closeQuietly(source);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public long contentLength() {
        try {
            return inputStream.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("file", "fname.pdf", pdffile)
        //.addFormDataPart("Documents", value) // uncomment if you want to send Json along with file
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(serverURL)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder().method(original.method(), original.body());
            builder.header("key", key);
            return chain.proceed(builder.build());
        })
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {
        // Handle the error
        setIsLoading(false);
        getNavigator().uploadIssue("Facing some issue to upload this file.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(final Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            getNavigator().uploadIssue("Facing some issue to upload this file.");

        }else {
            // Upload successful
            getNavigator().uploadedSucessfully();
        }

    }
});

return true;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Handle the error
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```