# How to get the list of pdf files of "Download" directory of the device in android 12?

Tags: android, pdf, filepicker.io

It shows other files like .jpg, .png, folders, .mp3 files but it doesn't show the .pdf, .doc files in the directory.

```
File Downloadpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.toString());

        String[] files = Downloadpath.list();

        Log.d("pdf", Arrays.toString(files));
        Log.d("pdf", "size:"+files.length);
        
        for(int k=0;k<files.length;k++){
            Log.d("pdf", "size:"+files[k]);
        }
```

How can I list the pdf files of Download folder in Android 12? I have tried  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972153/19179195) but it does not work in Android 12.

Comment: On Android 11+, you do not have access to arbitrary files placed in `Downloads/` by other apps, when using filesystem APIs [or `MediaStore`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html).

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does the job.

Comment: @blackapps You forgot to mention that using this permission is not a good idea if you are developing an app that will be published on Google Play as Google only allows apps to use this permission if it is required for a central feature of the app (e.g a file-manager app).